# UV unwrapping for AAA quality assets

Tags: uv

Just studying some game assets recently, below I have an image of a model I extracted from Fortnite with its UV Map.

How do they get the UV shells to layout so clean?l, like it's been projected from view but also unfolded and split at the seams? The small bevels around the bigger shells are also split off, yet perfectly aligned.
[image]

Here's what I've achieved so far on my own.

[image]

Comment: UV unwrap is mostly done manually, relaying on automatic unwrap can give you issues like distortions. Adding seams it's just the starting point for a good unwrap you need to invest time manually checking your distortions, use a checkerboard texture to see distortions

Comment: Are you saying I need to unwrap each piece/shell individually, as appose to unwrapping the whole thing at once? Because I manually placed all my seams and did a simple U + Unwrap. Im not quite sure what you mean by automatic unwrap.

Comment: That depends on the model, specifically for that model, yes, it looks like the original is a separe piece for some of the faces. Yes, placing seams is a manual process, but as I mentioned, it's just the beginning, there are other process that you need to do for some models, that requires manual manipulation of the vertices, edges and faces in order to achieve a good UV for texture paint

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It seems like thats working for me, just very tedious. Although Im still having troubles with the UV vertices merging together after I split them. Is there some sort of 'auto merge' in the UV editor I need to turn off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to many UV seams on the model.
Try marking seams only where you need them. This should result in less UV islands to deal with when you are editing the UV's and a more understandable UV layout when it comes time to texturing.

In the examples below note how the UV islands of the parts of the model that will almost never be seen (the back and bottom faces of the cupboard) have been scaled a lot smaller so that maximum UV space can be assigned to the rest of the UV islands.

Seams placed in such a way that each door/drawer panel will unwrap as a single UV island, including their bevelled edges. Then islands manually laid out in the UV space so that they will make sense when it comes time to use them.
[image]

Can we use fewer seams? :
[image]

Minimum number of seams? :
[image]